# Replace keys of an array with Value from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array structure like below

```
Array
(
    [1] => Dept1
    [2] => Dept2
    [3] => Dept3
)
```

And I have another Array as below

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [user1] => 58
            [user3] => 75
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user6] => 162
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [user7] => 2
            [user8] => 126
            [user9] => 148

        )
)
```

I want

```
Array
    (
        [Dept1] => Array
            (
                [user1] => 58
                [user3] => 75
            )

        [Dept2] => Array
            (
                [user6] => 162
            )

        [Dept3] => Array
            (
                [user7] => 2
                [user8] => 126
                [user9] => 148

            )
    )
```

The numbers in 2nd array are the department numbers. And their values are present in the first array. I want to replace the department number in second array with value from first array.

I have tried with **array_replace()** but don't get successful.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: show here your desire output array

Comment: of what type are the `DeptX`s? You can only use numbers and Strings as keys in an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the second array has less elements than your lookup array or if the keys are not in the same order, you need to map the key values first and then combine the arrays using [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine).

```
array_combine(array_map(function($key) use ($depts) {
    return $depts[$key]; // translate key to name
}, array_keys($dept_values)), $dept_values));
```

Otherwise, you can combine them immediately:

```
array_combine($depts, $dept_values);
```

See also: [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map)

Comment: it is giving error Both parameters should have an equal number of elements.

Comment: then any other solution please.

Comment: @1------- Update your question with the *actual* arrays you're working with would be a good start

Comment: It is same as actual array. Nothing different just values.

Comment: Okay . But I have 10 values in 2nd array and 9 values in first array.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Basically **join** and **explode** will do your work.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Copy to new array</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$dept= array('Dept1', 'Dept2', 'Dept3', 'Dept4');
$temp= join(",",$dept);
$department=explode(",",$temp);
echo "The first element in new array is: " . $department[0];
echo " and the second element in new array is: " . $department[1];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This code is working as expected for me:

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
print_r(array_combine($firstArray, $secondArray));
?>
```

**Array Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Dept1] => Array
        (
            [user1] => 58
            [user3] => 75
        )

    [Dept2] => Array
        (
            [user6] => 162
        )

    [Dept3] => Array
        (
            [user7] => 2
            [user8] => 126
            [user9] => 148
        )

)
```

Comment: I think person saw that you have answered same as Jack so he downvoted you. But one more thing this answer is valid only for the arrays with same values. And my array also has different values in some cases